# CSS positioning not working, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: css

I have been watching a tutorial on jQuery and he already had the css file made before but his output looks different than what I have when I downloaded the file

his:
[The way it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rirCZ.png)

Mine:
[image]

The code:

```
 #navArrows {
position: relative;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: 100px auto 0;
background: #333;
-webkit-border-radius: 100px;
-moz-border-radius: 100px;
border-radius: 100px;
padding: 20px;
}

.navigationArrow {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background: white;
    color: #222;
}

#up {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;

}

#left, #right {
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;

}
#left, {
    right: 20%;
    left: inherit;

}
#right {
    left: 20%;
    right: inherit;


}


#down {
    bottom: 20px;
    top: inherit;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px;

}

.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #a7f;
    color: white;
    border: solid 4px #a1f;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    opacity: 0.5;


    position: relative;

}
```

How do I fix this, please let me know.
ps: i added one part of the code that was missing from the original question, hope this helps.

Comment: go over the css and check for syntax mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was better if you was add the markup as well. However see the following example and make correction according it. Hope it will work for you.

```css
#navArrows {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  background: #333;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .navigationArrow {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   left: 20px;
   background: white;
   color: #222;
  }
  
  #up {
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -25px;
  
  }
  
  #left, #right {
   top: 50%; // One of the key line
   margin-top: -25px;
  
  }
  #right {
   left: auto;
   right: 20px;
  }
  
  
  #down {
   bottom: 20px;
   top: auto;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -25px; 
  
  }
  
  .box {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background: #a7f;
   color: white;
   border: solid 4px #a1f;
   line-height: 100px;
   margin: 100px auto 0;
   opacity: 0.5;
   position: relative;
  
  }
```

```html
<div id="navArrows">
 <div class="navigationArrow" id="up"></div>
    <div class="navigationArrow" id="right"></div>
    <div class="navigationArrow" id="down"></div>
    <div class="navigationArrow" id="left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a comma after the #left class try replacing it with:

```
#left {
    right: 20%;
    left: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but still same issue, nothing change.

I edited the code in the questions, was missing part of the code in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
#left {
    left: 0;
}
```